# how to rename wlp2s0 to wlan0 in ubuntu 17.04

Tags: networking

I have **ubuntu 17.04** ,but i cant use **aircrack-ng**.  i typed **"ifconfig"** but There isn't wlan0 only wlp2s0.  How change it? network

Answer (score 6):

To get an `ethX` and `wlanX` back, edit the grub file.

```
$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Look for `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` and add the following `net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0`.

From:

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

To:

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"
```

Generate a new grub file using the following command.

```
$ sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg

Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-15-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-15-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.bin
done
```

Restart `PC`

Comment: how i can save after change net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0 ?

Comment: Command to save is `ctrl`+`O` and to exit `ctrl`+`X`.

Comment: i entered ctrl + O but i cant exit using ctrl+X

Comment: `ctrl`+`O` then probably you need to hit enter `Enter`. This will save file. After that `ctrl` + `X` to exit from `nano`

Comment: If solution work for you, accept answer.

Comment: Thanks, searched quite a while for this and it works well!

Answer (score 1):

Hello guys I am providing a solution regarding this problem hope it will be helpfull for you....

1. you have to take entry into ***/etc/default/grub***
2. there one line will get changed and saved.
3. last is to configure accoding to ***GRUB*** and ***reboot***

so lets start:

first command

> **$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub**

aftet applying this command you will get the file of grub heres the fun guys
as you can see there is a line like this

> ***GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""***

now just simply type this string in those double quotes

> ***"net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"***

after this simple operation it will look something like this

> ***GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"***

now press ctrl+o (save)  and  ctrl+x (exit)....

second command

> $ sudo update-grub

third command

> $ sudo reboot

Thats it guys hope ur problem will be solved......;)

Answer (score 0):

Guys please dont rename it. It will make you pc network error
I trying that and i get error.
Try rename GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX = ""
And it will be fixed